# Python: Get data after second underscore from back?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get data after second underscore from back?

sample:

str

```
a_bc_def 12_23_this_6729

abc_def,122$3_this_6729

abc_def_1_2_23_this_6729
```

output

```
this_6729
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: second underscore from beginning, i got `str.split('_',2)[2]`

Comment: Use `r'(?<=_)[^_]*_[^_]*$'` in `re.findall`

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: `'_'.join(s.rsplit('_', 2)[-2:])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first split your string by the `'_'`, use a slice to get the last two  substrings, then join them again by `'_'`:

```
string = '''a_bc_def 12_23_this_6729

abc_def,122$3_this_6729

abc_def_1_2_23_this_6729'''

print('_'.join(string.split('_')[-2:]))
```

Output:

```
this_6729
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try rfind twice like

```
a = "a_bc_def 12_23_this_6729"
a[a[:a.rfind("_")].rfind("_") + 1:]
```

Output

```
'this_6729'
```